# Is there any way to transfer save data to a PS3 without overwriting the original save data?

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus

A while back, my old PS3 died. Recently, I got a new PS3 and started playing some games on it. Eventually, I'm going to see what I can do about getting someone to fix up the old PS3 so that I can get all of the old save data off of it. Problem is that I don't know if I'll be able to keep the save data that I have on my new PS3.

The only solution that I can think of is saving the save data from my new PS3 online through PS+ and then putting it back in. However, I'm worried that it'll overwrite the save data that's currently on the PS3, so one way or another, I'll end up giving up one set of save data for the other.

Is there any way that I can keep my old and new save data on one console?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have the option if you want to overwrite or not.

When copying data using the Save Data Utility, if the destination (whether the PS3, a storage device or the PS+ online storage) already has a save of the same game (on the same slot, if applicable), you'd see a prompt asking you if you wish to overwrite the save, so you can do the copy process without worrying of accidentally overwriting your save.

However, using a system transfer or restoring a backup completely removes any previous data on the target console, so if you wish to keep the saves on your new console, make sure to copy them beforehand to a storage device or PS+ storage, then restore them after the transfer/restore completes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data you want to keep from each console. When using the Backup or Data Transfer Utilities the destination system will be formatted and you can only keep the data of one console.

When you use an external HDD or USB thumb drive you should be able to copy everything except copy protected game saves, PSN titles and demos. Copying copy protected saves is only possible via Backup or online storage (sources: [here](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3/Merging-to-a-single-PS3-household/td-p/30260181) and [here](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3/How-to-Transfer-Saves-to-another-PS3/td-p/31057294)).

You may also run in another problem when trying to copy your game saves: some games use saves that are bound to your console and can't be copied to another console. [Here](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/general-ps3-discussion/62819-ps3ts-official-locked-saved-games-thread.html) is a quite comprehensive list of games with locked game saves.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your PS3 to a USB, you can go into settings and there is an option to transfer all data to the drive. You can then take it to another ps3 and input it into that and then just go into the same place in settings again and re-transfer your data.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me too, i went to a consoles store and got my old ps3 fixed and i transferred all my data over and kept my new data, when you save the data it gives you the option to overwrite.